# Default template parameter based on type of other template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I have a templated function as below:

```
template<typename T>
std::vector<RT> myFunc(std::vector<T> inVec){
    ...
    std::vector<RT> outVec;
    return outVec
```

I need the return type `RT` to be deduced from `T` with the logic that if `T` is `std::complex` then `RT` will be same as `T` but if not then `RT` will be `std::complex<T>`.

I tried defining a type trait to check if `T` is `std::complex` and have a default template parameter based on that as follows:

```
template<typename T>
struct is_complex : std::false_type {};

template<typename T> 
struct is_complex<std::complex<T>> : std::true_type {};

template<typename T, typename RT = typename is_complex<T>::value ? T : std::complex<T>>
std::vector<RT> myFunc(std::vector<T> inVec){
    ...
    std::vector<RT> outVec;
    return outVec
```

but this doesn't compile giving me the following error:

```
error: expected '>' before '?' token template<typename T, typename RT = typename is_complex<T>::value ? T : std::complex<T>>
```

Is this not legal C++ code?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this not legal C++ code?

Yes it's not valid syntax.

You can use [`std::conditional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/conditional).

```
template<typename T, typename RT = std::conditional_t<is_complex<T>::value, T, std::complex<T>>>
std::vector<RT> myFunc(std::vector<T> inVec){
    std::vector<RT> outVec;
    return outVec;
}
```

Or you can define the return type trait directly.

```
template <typename T>
struct rt {
    using type = std::complex<T>;
};

template <typename T>
struct rt<std::complex<T>> {
    using type = std::complex<T>;
};

template <typename T>
using rt_t = typename rt<T>::type;

template<typename T, typename RT = rt_t<T>>
std::vector<RT> myFunc(std::vector<T> inVec){
    std::vector<RT> outVec;
    return outVec;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the quick reply and the alternative solution.